# Where is the DLL with test to run with the nunit3 console generated?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit, nunit-console

I created a project in Visual Studio for unit testing using the nuget package of nunit. The test runs well in Visual Studio using the test explorer, but i Need to run them using the nunit3 console.

My project is very simple I:

- Created a console project in C#
- I Installed Nunit and NUnitTestAdapter using NuGet Package Manager.
- I create a  class called MyMath.cs with the next code:

  ```
  namespace NunitDemo
  {
  class MyMath
  {
      public int add(int a, int b)
      {
          return a + b;
      }

      public int sub(int a, int b)
      {
          return a - b;
      }
  }
  }
  ```
- I create a MyTestCase Class with the following code to test MyMath methods:

  ```
  using NUnit.Framework;
  using System;
  using System.Collections.Generic;
  using System.Linq;
  using System.Text;
  using System.Threading.Tasks;

  namespace NunitDemo
  {
      [TestFixture]
      class MyTestCase
      {
          [TestCase]
          public void Add()
          {
             MyMath math = new MyMath();
             Assert.AreEqual(31, math.add(20, 11));
          }

          [TestCase]
          public void Sub()
          {
          MyMath math = new MyMath();
          Assert.AreEqual(9, math.sub(20, 11));
          }
      }
  }
  ```
- I rebuild my solution and using The test explorer panel I can run my test in Visual Studio without problems.

But I need to run my test using the nunit3-console prompt, So, How Can I generate (Or Where Is) a DLL file to run test from the console o using nunit-gui?

I search inside C:\Users\Manuel\source\repos\ConsoleAppForNunit\ConsoleAppForNunit\bin\Debug but there is not a suitable .DLL

There is a Screenshot of that path: [image]

Answer (score 1):

From what you describe, you have never installed the NUnit Console application. You can find it in various places...

1. If you use chocolatey, use the choco command-line utility to install nunit-consolerunner.
2. If you prefer to have it installed in a project directory, install NUnit.ConsoleRunner from nuget.org. You can do this within visual studio.
3. You can download the files from the project site at https://github.com/nunit/nunit-console

Comment: Well, I actually have the nunit3-console, is located in C:\Program Files (x86)\NUnit.org\nunit-console for my case.

Comment: In that case, I don't understand what the problem is. You apparently installed it there using the `.msi` file. Why not jut use it?

Comment: Solved changing the project type from console to class library project. I will add a detailed solution latter.

Comment: NUnit3-console can run tests contained in either a dll or an exe.

Comment: @Charlie: thanks, I provided the exe and it was able to execute, so it need not be a dll.